# Changing QGIS plugin's icon, why doesn't it change in the menu/toolbar?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

I've been writing a QGIS plugin (using the "Plugin Builder" plugin), and decided I wanted to change the icon (icon.png).

After running **make deploy** to rebuild the plugin locally, the new icon appears in the Plugin Manager (both in the list of plugins, and the plugin description panel). So far, so good.

However, the old icon persists in the menu, and toolbar icons.

I've established that the icon.png is correct in the metadata.txt, and is getting copied into my **~/.qgis/python/plugins/myplugin** directory.

This is especially puzzling - I'm not replacing the default plugin icon, but an icon I previously created to replace the default plugin icon. So this has worked before... :/

I've tried these...

- restarting QGIS
- uninstall, then reinstall plugin using plugin manager
- destroy the plugin using **make derase** followed by **make deploy**
- reload the plugin using the "Plugin reloader" plugin

Does QGIS cache icons somewhere? That's the only explanation I can think of. If it does, is there any way to flush the cache?

I'm using QGIS 2.10.1 Pisa on Ubuntu 14.04. I'm using "Plugin Builder" version 2.8.3

I suspect it won't be a problem for anyone who hasn't installed the plugin before, but it's a bit strange.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

In QGIS 3, one needs to do

```
pyrcc5 -o resources.py resources.qrc
```

---

Original answer, valid for QGIS2:

Your plugin icon was converted to a byte array and saved in `resources.py`

So if you want to change this icon you have to compile your resources again:

```
pyrcc4 -o resources.py resources.qrc
```

Comment: after following your advice, and restarting QGIS, the icon has changed.. thank you!

Comment: .. and if that doesn't work, `make clean` followed by `make deploy` will remove the compiled resource and force the icon to be rebuilt

Comment: This gives me invalid syntax.

Comment: Why do you use pyrcc5 in the first command, and version 4 in the second?

Comment: The first command worked for me, not the 2nd one.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem, using QGIS Brighton 2.6.1 . I followed your intructions/tips and the solutions was:

- Open OSGeo4W Shell and change to the plugin folder MyPlugin by typing: 
  `cd C:\Program Files\QGIS Brighton\apps\qgis\python\plugins\MyPlugin`
- Type: `make clean` (removes the resource_rc.py)
- Type: `make deploy` (from resouce.qrc outputs new resource_rc.py)
- In QGIS plugin manager, disable and re-enable the plugin (outputs new compiled resource_rc.pyc)
  And the new pictures/logos changed.

Thanks!

Comment: if you dont have "make" then just run "pyrcc5 -o resources.py resources.qrc" (QGIS 3)

Answer (score 2):

I had some issue with this as well but solved it with changing the `icon_path` in the `initGui` function in my main script: `icon_path = f'{self.plugin_dir}/icon.png'` (from `icon_path = ':/plugins/plugin_name/icon.png'`)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to dmh126's answer make sure you haven't accidentally deleted the import and thus prevented the resources python code from compiling.  E.g. if your resources file is 'resources.py' -- assuming python files aren't nested -- you would search your project to make sure your code has the line:

```
import resources
```

Alternatively, you can delete `resources.pyc` and reload the plugin to ensure it is indeed getting compiled.