# How to change and display the plugins icon in the menu in QGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-2

I want to add multiple icons in the same file to display the plugins icons in the menu.

```
def initGui(self):
    action = self.add_action(   ':/plugins/Example/icons\icon1.png',
                                    text=self.tr(u'Example'),
                                    callback=self.ExampleMethod,
                                    parent=self.iface.mainWindow(),
                                    checkable=True,
                                    toolbar=self.ExampleToolbar)

        self.ExampleMethod = QgsMapTool(self.iface.mapCanvas())
        self.ExampleMethod.setAction(action)

        action = self.add_action(   ':/plugins/Example/icons\icon2.png',
                                    text=self.tr(u'Example1'),
                                    callback=self.ExampleMethod1,
                                    parent=self.iface.mainWindow(),
                                    checkable=True,
                                    toolbar=self.ExampleToolbar)

        self.ExampleMethod1 = QgsMapTool(self.iface.mapCanvas())
        self.ExampleMethod1.setAction(action)
```

but the problem is that the icons are not displaying.

I have used `make clean` and `make` commands and I have also updated the **resources.qrc** file.

What I have to do to display the icons in the menu?

Comment: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/162707/when-i-change-a-qgis-plugins-icon-why-doesnt-it-change-in-the-menu-toolbar/162708#162708

Comment: @dmh126 I have tried but didnt resolve the problem.

Answer (score 3):

You are mixing the two kinds of slash ("\" and "/") in your icon path. The escape sequence '\i' does not exist and it is interpreted as the simple character 'i'. For this reason the paths are not correct in:

```
.
.
.
    action = self.add_action(   ':/plugins/Example/icons\icon1.png',
.
.
.
    action = self.add_action(   ':/plugins/Example/icons\icon2.png',
.
.
.
```

and they are interpreted as:

```
:/plugins/Example/iconsicon1.png
```

and

```
:/plugins/Example/iconsicon2.png
```

respectively.

Try out this:

```
.
.
.
    action = self.add_action(   ':/plugins/Example/icons/icon1.png',
.
.
.
    action = self.add_action(   ':/plugins/Example/icons/icon2.png',
.
.
.
```

I hope this helps.