# Icon for plugins in own repository

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, icon, repository

Does anyone know if there is an opportunity to add icons for your own plug-in in its own repository? like this

[image]

not like this

[image]

with green puzzle

other illustration

[image]

I spied on how to implement it on the official website [here](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/plugins.xml) (view-source). File **plugins.xml** including the tag contains for example

`<icon>/static/packages/2015/icon_217.png</icon>`

where I added a similar relative path to my image (with and without leading slash)

`<icon>/favicon.png</icon>`,

but it does not appear in the list of plugins.
I did absolute path

`<icon>http://foo.bar.spam.ru/favicon.png</icon>`

but nothing had changed.

Comment: Perhaps this post might help: [When I change a QGIS plugin's icon, why doesn't it change in the menu/toolbar?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/162707/when-i-change-a-qgis-plugins-icon-why-doesnt-it-change-in-the-menu-toolbar)

Comment: No but thanks). Its different things. I about Plugin -> Manage Plugins dialog and why it does not show my icon.

Answer (score 3):

Thank you all for your advice.

I found a solution (by accident) [there](http://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/plugins.html#plugin-metadata) is somehow not very obvious described - but it was necessary to file metadata.txt correct **icons=desired_file.png**. **resource.py** for another bit.

Comment: Great! I forgot about metadata :(

Comment: All very strange that the map icons for installed plugins. In **plugins.xml** have the right tag (icon) could handle at this location and take (if found) the picture, and what-have much not to load too much to do pagination. P.S. Sorry for my english google translate not very helped me)

Answer (score 2):

1. Create a png file (23 x 24 pixel)
2. Create a resources.qrc file like this:

   `<RCC>
       <qresource prefix="/plugins/your_plugin_dir" >
          <file>icon.png</file>
       </qresource>
   </RCC>`

3.Compile the resource file to python

```
pyrcc4 -o resources_rc.py resources.qrc
```

4. Import the resources_rc.py file into your main plugin file

   `import resources_rc`

If you use the [PluginBuilder](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/pluginbuilder/) the resources.qrc and a Makefile are automaticly generated.

In the initGui method of the plugin you can add the same icon to toolbar and/or menu.

Comment: In the previous comments I have received exactly the same answer and comment on it.

Comment: this icon is displayed in manage plugin dialog. Download a plugin which has a custom icon and compare to your code.

Comment: i found!!! In metadata.txt icon=<your file> - what is all!