# Making 'make'-command work for compiling QGIS-plugins?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, osgeo4w

How can I compile my plugin when the 'make'-command refuses to work in the OSGeo4W Shell?

Can I make the 'make'-command work?

Is there an alternative out there?

I'm trying to build a plugin for QGIS. It's plugin Plugin Builder creates a projectfolder. According to [tutorials](http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/building_a_python_plugin.html) I have to open the OSGeo4W Shell and compile the resources of my plugin by navigating to the project folder and execute the make-command. However, this doesn't work for me, saying:

> 'make' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable
>   program or batch file.

I have a Windows sytem so that's not strange. Yet the OSGeo4W Shell should give me the abbility to use this command....I guesss. So I re-installed QGIS by using the Desktop Install by [OSGeo4w](https://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/) in hope that it would configure the libraries correctly. Sadly with no effect.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Thanks, I wish I asked the community earlier: I spended 3 hours solving this. With your answer: 1minute? I'm very gratefull!

Comment: Most welcome, glad it was helpful! Will post the comment as an answer for the convenience of others :)

Answer (score 3):

You only really need to compile the resources of your plugin, in which case you can use:

```
pyrcc4 -o resources.py resources.qrc
```

No need to use `make`. If you want to properly clean up your resources, you could use `make clean` as described in this post: [When I change a QGIS plugin's icon, why doesn't it change in the menu/toolbar?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/162707/when-i-change-a-qgis-plugins-icon-why-doesnt-it-change-in-the-menu-toolbar)

---

Also, from the tutorial link you gave, [a recent question was asked in the comments section](http://disq.us/p/1jtsabw) :)