# QGIS- Try writing plugin - neither 'make' nor 'pyrcc4' is known command

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-plugins, osgeo4w

I want to write a python plugin for QGIS 3.6.

Following the [Guide](http://www.qgistutorials.com/de/docs/building_a_python_plugin.html) I've installed the mentioned software **Qt Creator** and the  **OSGeo4W** . There is written, that in the OSGeo4W Shell It would be possible then to call the pyrcc4 command.

Later in the tutorial done by "make pyrcc4 ..."

However, nothing works on my machine.
No matter what I want to call, neither 'make' (like in Tutorial) nor 'pyrcc4' (like in some helps like this: [Making 'make'-command work for compiling QGIS-plugins?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/246626/making-make-command-work-for-compiling-qgis-plugin)) is a known command using the OSGeo4W Shell.

[image: Result]

I've also tried this:

[pyrcc4 command not recognized as internal or external command?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/312920/pyrcc4-command-not-recognized-as-internal-or-external-command)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you follow the **updated tutorial** for [QGIS 3](http://www.qgistutorials.com/de/docs/3/building_a_python_plugin.html)?

Comment: make sure to use the correct environment for pyqgis develeopment. On the console you'll need to execute py3_env.bat and qt5_env.bat. pyrcc5.bat for qgis3 is now in \apps\Python37\Scripts and py3_env.bat appends this to the path variable. Make isn't installed by default, it may be available as a osgeo4w package.

Comment: I think you should be using pb_tool now (after you run py3_env.bat)

Comment: Thanks @Joseph. Somehow I did not find this on searching. This works well. When you answer it, I'll mark it correct :)

Comment: @Malior - Most welcome, glad it helped :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [new updated guide for QGIS 3](http://www.qgistutorials.com/de/docs/3/building_a_python_plugin.html) where you need to use Qt5 and Python 3 libraries. Therefore, assuming you have set the relevant environments and ran the batch files as described in the guide (and mentioned by [@AndreasMüller](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/46073/andreas-m%c3%bcller) and [@IanTurton](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/79/ian-turton)), you would need to replace:

```
pyrcc4 -o resources_rc.py resources.qrc
```

with:

```
pyrcc5 -o resources.py resources.qrc
```