How to add new icon-image to custom QGIS 3.34-PlugIn?
I have created a plugin based on the plugin builder. In the plugin template code in the initGui method you set the path to the icon image:
def initGui(self):
    """Create the menu entries and toolbar icons inside the QGIS GUI."""

    icon_path = ':/plugins/reformat_LK/icon.png'
    self.add_action(
        icon_path,
        text=self.tr(u'Reformat data to specific LK-format'),
        callback=self.run,
        parent=self.iface.mainWindow())

    # will be set False in run()
    self.first_start = True

However, when I add a new png-image to the relevant folder and change the path to the image like this:
icon_path = ':/plugins/reformat_LK/icon-copy.png'

the menu is not created,or at least no menu item can be seen in QGIS (when reloading the QGIS Plugin reloader). So probably the image is not taken over?
I tried this even with the exact same image, just by copying it and changing the path to the copied image, so I assume it has something to do with the path, not with the image itself?
However, what causes it, and what can I do to use another image than the default 'icon.png'?

You must compile the resources file which converts your icon image to a byte array. See this question: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/162707

Or you can use an absolute path to your image that can be build dynamically. For example os.path.dirname(__file__) + '/icons/icon-copy.png'

In 2024 with QGIS 3.34 this worked:
Change the image path in the initGui-method to:
icon_path = f'{self.plugin_dir}/newIcon.png'

which corresponds to @YoLecomte answer (Thanks!).
What I tried and which DIDN'T work was (and which is suggested here Changing QGIS plugin's icon, why doesn't it change in the menu/toolbar? ):

deleting the .qrc-file and reload the plugin
using pyrcc5 -o resources.py resources.qrc (--> it ran without error but didn't seem to have any effect)
using make and deploy needs prior installment which I didn't know (see comments below), therefore I got the error 'unknown command' when I tried it, but will probably work, when you install it.

------ Update:
Some methods which didn't work for me actually will work, but needed more instructions than said in the discussion on Changing QGIS plugin's icon, why doesn't it change in the menu/toolbar?. Those missing instructions are explained in the comments from YoLecomte here below (especially regarding using pyrcc5).

QGIS3 and upper use QT5 so you need pyrcc5 -o resources.py resources.qrc 
Is your new image reference correctly added in your resources.qrc file before you run this command?

make is a program that need to be installed on your device. If you never install it, it's not surprising that you get an unknow command error...

Ah, okay! I thought it is something built-in to QGIS (as in in the referenced answer I didn't see that it is mentioned it needs to be installed). Thanks for the hint! I updated the answer accordingly

Oh, and I used the pyrcc5, not pyrcc4 (it was a typo in the answer here and I corrected it!)

@YoLecomte : I opened the .qrc with a texteditor and in there is still the old image referenced: <RCC>     <qresource prefix="/plugins/reformat_LK" >         <file>icon.png</file>     </qresource> </RCC>. Do I understand correctly, that another solution would be to change here the image to the new image? So instead of icon.png --> newImage.png?

yes that's right. You can also add more image in this file. They will be converted in the python file when you use the pyrcc5 command. See https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/resources.html

Thank you @YoLecomte! This was really valuable information!

May I ask why this answer and relevant comments, which are very helpful and adding lots of information (which cannot be found in the other discussion), got a downvote?This was really helpful!
